# Rpmbuild can't find file. Is missing folder in path

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild

Hi im trying to create my own rpm with rpmbuild. I have gone throught the basics no problem, But now im trying to make my own vim rpm, everything seem to go fine until the end when i get this output

```
+ '[' '%{buildarch}' = noarch ']'
+ QA_CHECK_RPATHS=1
+ case "${QA_CHECK_RPATHS:-}" in
+ /usr/lib/rpm/check-rpaths
+ /usr/lib/rpm/check-buildroot
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-compress
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-strip-static-archive /usr/bin/strip
+ /usr/lib/rpm/brp-python-bytecompile /usr/bin/python 1
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-python-hardlink
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-java-repack-jars
Processing files: vim-7.4-1.el7.x86_64
error: File not found: /home/me/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/vim-7.4-1.el7.x86_64/usr/bin/vim


RPM build errors:
    File not found: /home/me/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/vim-7.4-1.el7.x86_64/usr/bin/vim
```

Here also is my spec file

```
Name:       vim
Version:    7.4
Release:    1%{?dist}
Summary:    A text editor


License:    GPLv3+
URL:        https://blog.packagecloude.io
Source0:    vim.tar.gz


%description
A wicked text editor

%prep
%setup

%build
make PREFIX=/usr/local %{?_smp_mflags}

%install
make PREFIX=/usr/local DESTDIR=%{?buildroot} install

%clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}

%files
%{_bindir}/vim
```

I think im missing something simple.
This is the path i have

```
RPM build errors:
    File not found: /home/me/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/vim-7.4-1.el7.x86_64/usr/bin/vim
```

How can i change it to `/home/me/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/vim-7.4-1.el7.x86_64/usr/local/bin/vim`
.

Answer (score 1):

Probably if you analyze the output correctly you would see lines like:

> installing vim to /home/me/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/vim-7.4-1.el7.x86_64/usr/local/bin/vim

(note that he is installing to **/usr/local/bin** since you specified that.

however the macro `%_bindir` that you are using in the `%files` section expands to `/usr/bin`. So you have two options:

1. don't install under **/usr/local**; remove the `PREFIX=/usr/local` directives
2. keep installing in **/usr/local**; then you need to adapt your `%files` section

like this:

```
%files
/usr/local/bin/vim
```